# How to unset Cookies on static PHP generated CSS / JS files?

Tags: php, cookies, header, session-cookies, unset

Testing my site I saw a `Cookie score of 81/100`  with following comment:

`FAILED (Static object with 1 cookies - 36 bytes)` - all.css
cookie:PHPSESSID=3ge12i80ghj5gbb2cs41tr7qj5
`FAILED (Static object with 1 cookies - 36 bytes)` - all.js
cookie:PHPSESSID=3ge12i80ghj5gbb2cs41tr7qj5
`0.2 KB total in outbound cookies - potential savings = 0.2 KB`

Both files are actually PHP generated files, that combine many other css / js files into one.

**What should I do unset the cookie for these statis objects?**
Is there a php code that I can add next to the `headers();`  that can unset the cookie on those files?

Suggestions = answers = Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHPSESSID is going to be sent by the browser with every request to your current domain. It doesn't matter what file type is being requested (.html, .php, .js, .css, etc.). A good way to see this is using the "Live HTTP Headers" add-on for Firefox. You can see exactly what is being send with each request.

To prevent the PHPSESSID from being sent, you can serve these files from a different domain or possibly a sub-domain. The ideal solution is to use a CDN. However, I would not worry about the browser sending the PHPSESSID for these files.

Just out of curiosity, what tool are you using to test your site?

Comment: Alan's answer is correct. I was looking at this from the perspective of the browser as opposed to the server.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are calling `session_start` somewhere in those scripts.

If you remove that, the session cookie will not be set.

Comment: yeah, in the main php file. Does that mean automatically all loaded files will get that?